# SQL - Return all rows for ID where one row meets condition A,B,or C

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I'm trying to return all rows for a particular IDs where a condition is met in any one of the rows tied to those IDs. Pardon me being a newbie to SQL... Example below:

---

- ID * Line * # *

  ---
- 12 *  1  *  A *
- 12 *  2  *  B *
- 12 *  3  *  X *
- 12 *  4  *  Y *
- 15 *  1  *  A *
- 15 *  2  *  B *
- 15 *  3  *  C *

  ---

Not sure what the code would be other than my select and condition = (X, Y, or Z) to return:

---

- ID * Line * # *

  ---
- 12 *  1  *  A * <-- doesn't include X, Y, or Z but is part of the ID which
- 12 *  2  *  B * <-- has X in another row of that ID
- 12 *  3  *  X *
- 12 *  4  *  Y *

  ---

I'm wanting to pull all row records despite not meeting the condition as long as they're part of the ID that has a row that meets the condition.

Thanks for the help!

*** Edit: Including code attempted***

```
SELECT ID
,LINE 
,#
    WHERE   ID,
IN (
SELECT ID
WHERE # IN ('X','Y','Z'))
```

Results:

```
ID  LINE  #
12   3    X
12   4    Y
```

What I need:

```
ID  LINE  #
12   1    A
12   2    B
12   3    X
12   4    Y
```

I almost feel like I need to create a temp table of ID & LINE using my condition of IN('X','Y','Z') and then inner join on ID for all LINE(s) not X,Y,Z. I think that may work, but I haven't learned how to use temp tables yet. I'm a little troubled because I'm using a query, which I've simplified a ton here, where I'm selecting 18 fields that join in 7 other tables. I think this is just complicating my understanding of the subquery, not so much the subquery being affected by that.

Thanks all for the help and answers so far!

Comment: is that three columns or a single column?

Comment: Use a sub query to identify the ID and then use that with ID `IN` to return the actual rows

Comment: scsimon's code should work swhen used correctly. Did you try my OLAP-approach?

Comment: Should I include that code with all of my select statements before my joins?  my query is structured as SELECT (17 fields), FROM, JOIN (many joins), WHERE - this is where I have the code above and other conditions.

Comment: Yes, that's it, simply add that `MAX(CASE)` to your existing Select

Comment: So I was able to get this to work without using a subquery or the OLAP approach, unless I'm missing something. I was really just messing around with the different approaches and comparing against my original when it pulled correctly using just IN ('X','Y','Z') in my conditions. What I did was move the condition to before another Group By which Groups ID and LINE. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery and `IN` for this.

```
Select *
From YourTable
where ID in (select ID from YourTable where # in ('X','Y','Z'))
```

Just a note, there is no `12 * 4 * C *` in your data but I think it's just a type-o in your results and should be `12 * 4 * Y *`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sure this is on the right track. I tried this, but unfortunately I have like 7 tables joined to return different fields I need and I cannot get this to work. I'm not sure if that's cause it, but it may be. I have each ID which has many LINE(s) tied to it, and each LINE has a #. When I use this, I'm still only returning the # that I'm entering in my conditions (X, Y, Z). I've tested by selecting a specific ID without the condition and it comes back with more LINE(s) without (X, Y, Z). I'm going to keep trying the subquery approach.

Comment: @CGermain post your code in your original question that correlates to your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the subquery approach you might also try an OLAP-function (Depending on the actual data this might be better or worse, of course)

In Teradata you can apply QUALIFY:

```
Select *
From YourTable
qualify -- check if any row with the same ID has X/Y/Z
   max(case when ID in ('X','Y','Z') then 1 else 0 end)
   over (partition by ID) = 1
```

In SQL Server you have to use a Derived Table/CTE:

```
Select *
From 
 ( Select *,
      max(case when ID in ('X','Y','Z') then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by ID) as flag
   from YourTable
 ) as dt
where flag = 1
```